# How do I make a Hazelcast client wait for the server to start up?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast client application which will sometimes be started before any server in the cluster. Before I start building this myself.

Is there any built in support in Hazelcast to make the client wait for the cluster to start up and then connect to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can set the connectionAttemptLimit on the ClientConfig.

connectionAttemptLimit: the maximum numbers of times to try the addresses
to connect to the cluster, defaults to 2. When a client starts or a the client
looses connecting with the cluster, it will try to make a connection with one
of the cluster member addresses. In some cases a client can’t connect to these
addresses, e.g. the cluster is not yet up or not reachable. Instead of giving
up, one can increase the attempt limit to create a connection. Also have a
look at the connectionAttemptPeriod.

Comment: What's the equivalent hazelcast property for this configuration? e.g. hazelcast.client.???

Comment: it isn't available as a system property afaik. You need to set it on the client config.

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it worked for me:
    `<hz:network connection-attempt-limit="50"
      connection-attempt-period="5000"
      connection-timeout="1000"
      redo-operation="true">
   <hz:member>`